# Is it OK that I request a considerable amount of access token not reusing API?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, android-authenticator

In Android API, `access token` can be re-issued through `refresh token`.

Even after new `access token` is issued, the previous one is still valid for expire time(maybe 1 hour).

I am wondering if it is ok to request a new `access token` everytime I need regardless of how many `access token` is issued so that I don't mind if the `access token` is expired or not.

With my simple test, It seems OK. However, I am not sure it is still OK with production service.

Any expected issue, if I request a considerable amount of `access token` with a refresh token?

Otherwise, should I re-use `access token` until it is expired?